# URL rewrite with an already rewritten URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, koken

I want to implement a redirect via `.htaccess` from the old URL:

```
http://derpiet.de/photos/ireland
```

to the URL:

```
http://derpiet.de/photos/alben/2013/07/ireland
```

The system in the background is koken (http://koken.me).

Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

So, this will work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/photos/ireland/$
RewriteRule .* alben/2013/05/ireland [L,R=301]
```